# Problema “Unable to copy file” WindowsForms C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Tengo un problema, cambié una de las opciones en el archivo de configuración de mi aplicación, más específicamente, el apartado de 32 bits y 64, pero después lo regresé a la normalidad (La opción por defecto : "Any CPU"), e intenté ejecutar mi app, pero me apareció este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola. Borra la carpeta `obj` y `bin` y todo su contenido. Si tuvieras bloqueado algún fichero, cierra `Visual Studio` y elimina dichas carpetas.

Answer (score 2):

Es posible que algún proceso esté bloqueando esos ficheros en Debug y Visual Studio no puede sobreescribirlos con una nueva versión. Botón derecho en el Solution Explorer, open folder in file explorer, cierra Visual Studio, borra Debug y vuelve a abrir el proyecto. Si esto no funciona entonces deberás usar control+alt+del para matar el proceso (en el mensaje de error dice que se llama "Remainder") o reiniciar el PC antes de borrar Debug.